# Ansible is re-provision the same host even though inventory file setup correctly

Tags: ansible, vagrant, virtual-machine, provisioning

I've been trying to debug this for a while now, and I thought I had it working, but then made some other changes, and now back again.

Basically, I have Vagrant looping over a list of machines definitions and while my Ansible inventory looks perfectly fine, I find that only one host is actually being provisioned.

Generated Ansible Inventory -- The SSH ports are all different, groups are correct

```
# Generated by Vagrant

kafka.cp.vagrant ansible_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_port=2200 ansible_user='vagrant' ansible_ssh_private_key_file='/workspace/confluent/cp-ansible/vagrant/.vagrant/machines/kafka.cp.vagrant/virtualbox/private_key' kafka='{"broker": {"id": 1}}'
zk.cp.vagrant ansible_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_port=2222 ansible_user='vagrant' ansible_ssh_private_key_file='/workspace/confluent/cp-ansible/vagrant/.vagrant/machines/zk.cp.vagrant/virtualbox/private_key'
connect.cp.vagrant ansible_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_port=2201 ansible_user='vagrant' ansible_ssh_private_key_file='/workspace/confluent/cp-ansible/vagrant/.vagrant/machines/connect.cp.vagrant/virtualbox/private_key'

[preflight]
zk.cp.vagrant
kafka.cp.vagrant
connect.cp.vagrant

[zookeeper]
zk.cp.vagrant

[broker]
kafka.cp.vagrant

[schema-registry]
kafka.cp.vagrant

[connect-distributed]
connect.cp.vagrant
```

Generated hosts file -- IPs and hostnames are correct

```
## vagrant-hostmanager-start id: aca1499c-a63f-4747-b39e-0e71ae289576
192.168.100.101 zk.cp.vagrant

192.168.100.102 kafka.cp.vagrant

192.168.100.103 connect.cp.vagrant

## vagrant-hostmanager-end
```

Ansible Playbook I want to run -- Correctly correspond to the groups in my inventory

```
- hosts: preflight
  tasks:
  - import_role:
      name: confluent.preflight
- hosts: zookeeper
  tasks:
  - import_role:
      name: confluent.zookeeper
- hosts: broker
  tasks:
  - import_role:
      name: confluent.kafka-broker
- hosts: schema-registry
  tasks:
  - import_role:
      name: confluent.schema-registry
- hosts: connect-distributed
  tasks:
  - import_role:
      name: confluent.connect-distributed
```

For any code missing here, see [Confluent :: cp-ansible](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-ansible).

The following is a sample of my Vagrantfile. (I [made a fork](https://github.com/cricket007/cp-ansible/tree/addVagrant/vagrant), but haven't committed until I get this working...)

I know that this `if index == machines.length - 1` should work [according to the Vagrant documentation](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/ansible.html), and it does start all the machines, then only runs Ansible on the last machine, but its just all the tasks are executed on **first** one for some reason.

```rb
machines = {"zk"=>{"ports"=>{2181=>nil}, "groups"=>["preflight", "zookeeper"]}, "kafka"=>{"memory"=>3072, "cpus"=>2, "ports"=>{9092=>nil, 8081=>nil}, "groups"=>["preflight", "broker", "schema-registry"], "vars"=>{"kafka"=>"{\"broker\": {\"id\": 1}}"}}, "connect"=>{"ports"=>{8083=>nil}, "groups"=>["preflight", "connect-distributed"]}}

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  if Vagrant.has_plugin?("vagrant-hostmanager")
    config.hostmanager.enabled = true
    config.hostmanager.manage_host = true
    config.hostmanager.ignore_private_ip = false
    config.hostmanager.include_offline = true
  end

  # More info on http://fgrehm.viewdocs.io/vagrant-cachier/usage
  if Vagrant.has_plugin?("vagrant-cachier")
    config.cache.scope = :box
  end

  if Vagrant.has_plugin?("vagrant-vbguest")
    config.vbguest.auto_update = false
  end

  config.vm.box = VAGRANT_BOX
  config.vm.box_check_update = false
  config.vm.synced_folder '.', '/vagrant', disabled: true

  machines.each_with_index do |(machine, machine_conf), index|
    hostname = getFqdn(machine.to_s)

    config.vm.define hostname do |v|
      v.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.100.#{101+index}"
      v.vm.hostname = hostname

      machine_conf['ports'].each do |guest_port, host_port|
        if host_port.nil?
          host_port = guest_port
        end
        v.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: guest_port, host: host_port
      end

      v.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
        vb.memory = machine_conf['memory'] || 1536 # Give overhead for 1G default java heaps
        vb.cpus = machine_conf['cpus'] || 1
      end

      if index == machines.length - 1
        v.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
          ansible.compatibility_mode = '2.0'
          ansible.limit = 'all'
          ansible.playbook = "../plaintext/all.yml"
          ansible.become = true
          ansible.verbose = "vv"

          # ... defined host and group variables here

        end # Ansible provisioner
      end # If last machine
    end # machine configuration
  end # for each machine
end
```

I setup an Ansible task like this

```
- debug:
    msg: "FQDN: {{ansible_fqdn}}; Hostname: {{inventory_hostname}}; IPv4: {{ansible_default_ipv4.address}}"
```

Just with that task, notice that the following `ansible_fqdn` is **always** `zk.cp.vagrant`, and this lines up with the fact that only that VM is getting provisioned by Ansible.

```
ok: [zk.cp.vagrant] => {
    "msg": "FQDN: zk.cp.vagrant; Hostname: zk.cp.vagrant; IPv4: 10.0.2.15"
}
ok: [kafka.cp.vagrant] => {
    "msg": "FQDN: zk.cp.vagrant; Hostname: kafka.cp.vagrant; IPv4: 10.0.2.15"
}
ok: [connect.cp.vagrant] => {
    "msg": "FQDN: zk.cp.vagrant; Hostname: connect.cp.vagrant; IPv4: 10.0.2.15"
}
```

Update with minimal example: `hostname -f` is only one host, and I assume that's what `gather_facts` is running for `ansible_fqdn`

```
ansible all --private-key=~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key --inventory-file=/workspace/confluent/cp-ansible/vagrant/.vagrant/provisioners/ansible/inventory -a 'hostname -f' -f1
```

```
zk.cp.vagrant | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
kafka.cp.vagrant

connect.cp.vagrant | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
kafka.cp.vagrant

kafka.cp.vagrant | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
kafka.cp.vagrant
```

Comment: might be related https://grokbase.com/t/gg/ansible-project/14bm1x0pgs/ansible-facts-help-ansible-fqdn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I can get around the problem with **not** having this section in my `ansible.cfg`

```
[ssh_connection]
control_path = %(directory)s/%%h-%%r
```